# Passing result of one batch file to another?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file (BAT1.bat) which returns the following string:

"Login credential: 7o5g4cika"

I need to send a part of the result (ie "7o5g4cika") as argument to another bat file BAT2.bat.

```
BAT2.bat 7o5g4cika
```

How can I combine these to a single bat file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line will do what you want:

```
for /F "tokens=3" %v in ('BAT1.bat') do call BAT2.bat %v
```

What this line does is call `BAT1.bat`, then parses its output using the options specified after the `/F`. Specifically, `"tokens=3"` tells the shell to take the third token and put it in the variable. Then, `BAT2.bat` is called with the variable as its parameter.

Assuming you are going to use this in a batch file, you're going to want to double the percent signs:

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%v in ('BAT1.bat') do call BAT2.bat %%v
```

For more details, type

```
for /?
```

from the command line

Answer (score -1):

Make a call like `Bat1.bat | Bat2.bat` then put some code at the beginning of **bat2.bat** to get the right substring.

If you can't touch **bat2.bat**, create a **bat3.bat**, dedicated to tweak "*Login credential: 7o5g4cika*" into "*7o5g4cika*" and make a call like: `Bat1.bat | Bat3.bat | Bat2.bat`

Comment: You want to append the text to another batch file?